# How to run Algolia Firestore extension import script?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, algolia, firebase-extensions

I'm installing the [Algolia extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search) for Firestore. Setup works just fine and it updates indices on add delete and update. But now I want to backfill it with existing data.

The following steps are provided in the setup guide but I have no clue on HOW to run that script. I've tried pasting it directly in node shell and powershell, adding it to a js or ps1 file and running that but I don't know what kind of script this is.

[image: Firestore console]

How do I run this script? (I have a service account json next to it)

Comment: did you actually make this work? For me when running the script, the command is not completing. Also have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75423907/correctly-import-data-from-firestore-to-algolia) question up. Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's bash...

It works when pasted directly in bash with spaces on each newline after the line terminator. Or as a `.sh` file from the commandline.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCATION=europe-west3\
  ALGOLIA_APP_ID=xxx\
  ALGOLIA_API_KEY=xxx\
  ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME=organizations\
  COLLECTION_PATH=organizations\
  FIELDS=name,address,city\
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./xxx.json\
  npx firestore-algolia-search
```

Comment: *firebaser here* Thanks for flagging and clarifying the documentation Jonathan.  
 This could/should indeed have been made clearer in those instructions. I've flagged it with the team.

Comment: Frank this still has not been made clear. I have to this day still not have been successfull at running this script.