# Correctly import data from FireStore to Algolia

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia, firebase-extensions

I am trying to import existing data from `firestore` to `Algolia` but can not make it work. I installed the *Firebase Algolia Extension` and tried to follow the documented steps:

1. running this:

> `npx firestore-algolia-search`

Below are the questions that will be asked:

What is the Region? europe-west3

What is the Project Id? wishlist-88d58

What is the Algolia App Id? 15W2O5H8ZN

What is the Algolia Api Key? { unspecified parameter }

What is the Algolia Index Name? allUsers

What is the Collection Path? allUsers
What are the Fields to extract? { unspecified parameter }

What is the Transform Function? { unspecified parameter }

What is the path to the Google Application Credential File? wishlists_key.json

For the Algolia API Key I added a key: [image]

I did not specify *Fields to extracts* and *Transform Functions*.

For *path to the Google Application Credential File* I created a *private key* in Firebase and located it on the my desktop as `wishlists_key.json`, which is where I ran the command above from.

I got a response which also contained the data but said at the beginning there was an error:

> {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"}
> {"location":"europa-west3","algoliaAppId":"15W205H8ZN","algoliaAPIKey":"********","algoliaIndexName":"allUsers","collectionPath":"allUsers","fields":"","transformFunction":"","projectId":"wishlist-88d58","severity":"INFO","message":"Initializing extension with configuration"}
> {"severity":"INFO","message":"[ 'Sending rest of the Records to Algolia' ]"}
> {"severity":"INFO","message":"[ 'Preparing to send 20 record(s) to Algolia.' ]"}
> {"name":"RetryError","message":"Error when performing Algolia index","transporterStackTrace":[{"request":{"data":"{"requests":[{"action":"partialUpdateObject","body":{"signInMethod":"mail","username":"user662572"

> ...

The command does not finish running but get's stuck in this.

What am I doing wrong here? **How do I correctly import data from FireStore to Algolia?**

Also, later I will need to import a collection with about 24k documents. Is the documented way also capable of handling these amount of documents?

Comment: Can you have a look at this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315120/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65539757/18265570)

Comment: @RoopaM I tried running it on the Cloud Shell but same error. I don't know how to properly setup up the variables or run it correctly. Everytime the same error. Did you make it work?

Comment: I tried on my linux terminal, Initially I also faced same issue as I was using default `Algolia `API key. Then I created new API key with the same `ACLs` you are using, after that I can able to import `firestore` collection to `Algolia`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work through Google Cloud Shell. I had to import my `Google Application Credential File` to it, ran the command above again.

I still got the same Warning that it will fail, but it worked anyway and all data was correctly imported.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to running the backfill script, you can write an admin script to update each document and the extension's code will sync each document to Algolia